# Ionic 3 Local Notifications are not sent

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm having a problem with localNotification. What I'm doing is a series of multiple notifications sent during breakfast, lunch and dinner Notification are not sent, this is my code, does anyone know how I can solve and explain where I am wrong?

```
this.dateObjectBreakfast = moment("2018-08-05 09:00", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").toDate();
this.dateObjectLunch = moment("2018-08-05 12:00", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").toDate();
this.dateObjectDinner = moment("2018-08-05 19:00", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").toDate();
console.log(this.dateObjectBreakfast);
this.localNotifications.schedule([
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'My Second notification',
        text: 'Second notification',
        trigger: {at: this.dateObjectBreakfast, every: ELocalNotificationTriggerUnit.DAY},
        data: {"id": 1, "name": "Mr. B"}
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'My Second notification',
        text: 'Second notification',
        trigger: {at: this.dateObjectBreakfast, every: ELocalNotificationTriggerUnit.DAY},
        data: {"id": 2, "name": "Mr. B"}
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'My third notification',
        text: 'Third notification',
        trigger: {at: this.dateObjectBreakfast, every: ELocalNotificationTriggerUnit.DAY},
        data: {"id": 2, "name": "Mr. B"}
    }
]);
```